# How to config libvirt network setting about disabling dnsmasq "except-interface=lo"?

Tags: domain-name-system, virtualization, dhcp, libvirt, dnsmasq

Here is the thing.
My VMs run with `libvirt` and use default network libvirt-provide, and I've mad each VM registers its hostname to `dnsmasq` set by `libvirt`. so I want to look up its hostname for reachable.

But the `libvirt` always enables `except-interface=lo` for `dnsmasq` as arguments, it makes me overwrite the `dnsmasq.conf` in `/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq/default.conf` and restarts `dnsmasq` manually every time. I cannot find out how to solve this issue at `libvirt` [network xmlformat documentation](http://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html).

Any help will be appreciated.